# JFrames inside JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I currently have build an application where I use multiple frames.
But it would be nice if I could use the frames I used all in just 1 frame.
Like in the image below.

[image]

So if you press the left button "Speler Overzicht" that it will show the users in the right panel and I still have my buttons in the left panel.

[image]

Comment: The image you posted is only 1 `JFrame`, possibly containing multiple `JPanel` instances

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it's a very bad idea to base you UI classes on `JFrame`, as it locks you into a single use case, meaning you can't add the UI component (frame) to other containers.

I better solution is to base your UI components on `JPanel`s, which then allows you to add them to where ever you need them.  It also makes life easier to extend them, but that's another story.

To allow the user to move between multiple views, you can use either a `CardLayout` or `JTabbedPane` depending on your needs

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use JPanels instead.

```
buttonPanel=new JPanel();
overzichtPanel=new JPanel();

buttonPanel.add(button);// do this for every button
overzichtPanel.add(componentsYouWantToAdd);// replace with your variables of course 

frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST)
frame.add(overzichtPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put one JFrame inside another. You have a some design choices here. You can change your JFrames to JPanels. This is probably the easiest change. On the other hand, you can look at using [Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) instead.